# Pull in month value dynamically from another cell using query()

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I have two sheets of data, the second sheet is "DATA".

The primary sheet I'm using, I have a =query() to query the other sheet based on a month number. From my research, I found this - https://www.benlcollins.com/spreadsheets/query-dates/ - which by itself, does work, but within query(), doesn't work.

Data:

1/1/18  2/1/18  3/1/18  4/1/18

Broken function:

`=IFERROR(QUERY(DATA!$A:$L, "Select sum(G) WHERE B contains lower('"&$A4&"') AND MONTH(A)+1='"&TEXT(DATEVALUE(C1),"m")&"' label sum(G) ''"),"$0")`

Working function:

`=IFERROR(QUERY(DATA!$A:$L, "Select sum(G) WHERE B contains lower('"&$A4&"') AND MONTH(A)+1=4 label sum(G) ''"),"$0")`

Problem...is that I want it to be dynamic.

When I use

`'"&TEXT(DATEVALUE("1/1/2000"),"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'`

as a function, it renders as a "4" which is what the query() is looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about something like

```
=IFERROR(QUERY(DATA!$A:$L, "Select sum(G) WHERE B contains lower('"&$A4&"') AND MONTH(A)+1= "&MONTH(C1)&" label sum(G) ''"),"$0")
```

Comment: That worked! Thanks. It ended up just taking a little longer to process, so maybe I thought it hadn't worked before. Cheers

Comment: @JonDingman: If the suggested formula worked, please accept answere or upvote.